# Need some help for my newly planted cherry tree

Tags: fruit-trees, containers, cherries

It is a Summit cherry tree, planted one month ago in a container. Recently most of its leaves and sprouts became droopy and it also has fewer leaves compared 2 other cherry trees planted around the same time.

I've checked the soil and top 2 inches were moist. For the one with drooped leaves, it was pruned 3 times before it sprouted since I have little experience in pruning fruit trees. The other two though was pruned in one go.

I have no idea what happened and what should I do to save the tree. Friends pls help.
Thanks

Update: there was very little sap oozed from the cutting point
[image: This is the cherry tree mentioned above]

[image: This are two healthy cherry trees planted at the same time]

Answer (score 0):

I think its not being watered enough.  You should drench it periodically.  The roots aren't at the top, they are deeper.  Invest in a drip feeder.  Something like this is cheap

[image]